# How to use Hakyll.loadSnapshot without "No instance for (Typeable a0)" error

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I'm trying to add some functionality to my site so that I can expose different versions of a post. For example, if my source directory contains

```
mypost/version/1
mypost/version/2
mypost/version/3
```

I'd like to copy all of the versions of the post into the generated site, along with a new path `mypost/version/latest`.

To accomplish this, I compile each version of the post and take a snapshot using `saveSnapshot`. Then I iterate over everything in the `mypost/version` directory to find the latest version. Finally, I want to get the compiled snapshot of the latest version and copy it into the `mypost/version/latest` directory.

In my site generator, I pass the output of `loadSnapshot` into an item-copying compiler, along the lines of:

```
loadSnapshotAndCopy :: Snapshot -> Compiler (Item CopyFile)
loadSnapshotAndCopy snapshot = do
  identifier <- getUnderlying
  item <- loadSnapshot identifier snapshot
  provider <- compilerProvider <$> compilerAsk
  makeItem $ CopyFile $ resourceFilePath provider (itemIdentifier item)
```

However, this produces an error:

```
    • No instance for (Typeable a0)
        arising from a use of ‘loadSnapshot’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        item <- loadSnapshot identifier snapshot
      In the expression:
        do identifier <- getUnderlying
           item <- loadSnapshot identifier snapshot
           provider <- compilerProvider <$> compilerAsk
           makeItem
             $ CopyFile $ resourceFilePath provider (itemIdentifier item)
      In an equation for ‘loadSnapshotAndCopy’:
          loadSnapshotAndCopy snapshot
            = do identifier <- getUnderlying
                 item <- loadSnapshot identifier snapshot
                 provider <- compilerProvider <$> compilerAsk
                 ....
    |
248 |   item <- loadSnapshot identifier snapshot
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The type of `loadSnapshot` is `loadSnapshot :: (Binary a, Typeable a) => Identifier -> Snapshot -> Compiler (Item a)`, so I guess there's a constraint that the compiler is unable to satisfy for some reason. How can get around this in order to use `loadSnapshot`?

Comment: I'd try replacing `(itemIdentifier item)` with `(itemIdentifier (item :: TheTypeYouExpectItemToHave))` so to tell Haskell the expected type of `item`, which apparently can not be inferred from the rest of the code.

Comment: Hakyll snapshots are primarily meant to save intermediate versions of content being processed, while `copyFileCompiler` (upon which you have based `loadSnapshotAndCopy`) doesn't actually look at the contents of the file being compiled (which is presumably why `CopyFile` doesn't have the `Typeable` instance expected by `loadSnapshot` and friends). Those two approaches are at odds, so I suspect you'll have to drop one of them. Please add the code that compiles each version of the post and takes the snapshots, as I feel that will make it easier for us to give useful suggestions.